# A question about exact sequences of modules and endomorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

$\require{AMScd}$
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and 
\begin{CD}
    0 @>>>A @>f>> B@>g>> C@>>>0
\end{CD} 
a short exact sequence of left $R$-modules. Let $\phi_A$, $\phi_B$, and $\phi_C$ be module endomorphisms of $A$, $B$, and $C$, respectively, such that the diagram 
\begin{CD}
0 @>>>A @>f>> B@>g>> C@>>>0\\
_@V \phi_A V V @V \phi_B V V @V \phi_C V V\\
0 @>>>A @>f>> B@>g>> C@>>>0
\end{CD}
commutes. I am trying to prove that $\phi_B =\text{id}_B$ if and only if $\phi_A =\text{id}_A$ and $\phi_C =\text{id}_C$. It is easy to show that if $\phi_B =\text{id}_B$, then $\phi_A =\text{id}_A$ and $\phi_C =\text{id}_C$ using commutativity and the fact that $f$ is injective and $g$ surjective. How might I prove the other direction? I have tried chasing elements but cannot get the result.

The claim may also be false, so a counterexample would be useful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$

The direction you want to prove is false.  Good sources of examples are non-split sequences.  Having a middle term with non-trivial automorphisms helps.  Everything in my counterexample will be in the category of abelian groups.

Consider the diagram
\begin{CD}
0 @>>>\mathbb{Z}_2 @>f>> \mathbb{Z}_4@>g>> \mathbb{Z}_2@>>>0\\
_@V 1_A V V @V \phi V V @V 1_C V V\\
0 @>>>\mathbb{Z}_2 @>f>> \mathbb{Z}_4@>g>> \mathbb{Z}_2@>>>0
\end{CD}
where $f(1) =2$, $g(1)=1$, and $\phi(1)=3$.  (I need only describe these maps on $1$ since they're all cyclic groups.)

You can check that my sequence is exact:  it just realizes the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}_4/\langle 2 \rangle$ as isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  You may also check that the entire diagram commutes:
$$
\phi (f(1))= \phi(2) = 3+3 = 2= f(1)
$$
and
$$
g(\phi(1))=g(3)= 3 =1 = g(1).
$$
Certainly, $\phi \neq 1_{\mathbb{Z}_4}$.